# Apply css style to all IE browsers

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Here is the css I wish to improve upon:

```
img {
    border-radius: 7px 90px 7px 7px !important;
    @include pie;
    .ie8 &{
        margin-left: 1px;
        border-radius: 7px 90px 7px 7px;
    }       
    .ie9 &{
        margin-left: 1px;
        border-radius: 7px 90px 7px 7px;
    }       
    .ie10 &{
        margin-left: 1px;
        border-radius: 7px 90px 7px 7px;
    }       
    .ie11 &{
        margin-left: 1px;
        border-radius: 7px 90px 7px 7px;
    }       
}
```

Is there a way of specifying the style for all IE browser versions? Instead of 1 class for each browser version?

The answers I found so far are:

1. Hack
2. Apply 'If' condition in HTML

Refer this link for details - http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

Ques:

1. Is there any other solution apart from the above 2?
2. Has anyone successfully implemented the hacks? They don't work for me. Either breaks the styling or does nothing!

Thanks!
Neha

Comment: I'd rather use a feature detector like [Modernizer](http://modernizr.com/).

Comment: Maybe downgrade your any IE version to IE8 using this: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a conditional statement to set the `<html>` tag?

You can apply a class to the entire page with:

```
<!--[if !IE]><!--><html><!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE]><html class="ie"><![endif]-->
```

Then set your CSS to apply a rule to `.ie`:

```
.ie{
  img{ /* ie only properties */ }
}
```

Comment: [Conditional comments no longer work in IE>9.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801214%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: You could add the class with JavaScript instead.